# C# Attach properties? to enum

Tags: c#, enums, attributes

I have an enum:

```
enum RANK
{
    kingdom=0,
    phylum=1,
    order=2,
    family=3,
    genus=4,
    species=5
}
```

where each item has a parent (the rank above) and child (the rank below). Out of bounds errors (e.g. trying to find the parent of a kingdom) result in an exception. The questions is whether it is possible to attach an attribute (or anything really) to the enum so that it can be called:

```
RANK child = kingdom.Child;
RANK parent = species.Parent;
```

I have code to call this as a function (which is on the border of my understanding)

```
public static RANK GetParent(this RANK rank)
    {
        if ((rank - 1) > (RANK)0)
        {
            return rank - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("No parent rank");
        }
    }
```

with corresponding GetChild version. Called as:

```
RANK child = kingdom.GetChild();
RANK parent = species.GetPArent();
```

This is annoying me, as it's not really a function call but a variable call, and should really be called as such. I'm open to suggestions, however I need enum-type behaviour from the result (fixed list and called in the same way, this is going to be near non-technical people!) So long as it looks like an enum and behaves like an enum, it'll pass as an enum.

Comment: Exactly how much enum behaviour do you need? For example, do you need to be able to switch on the result? (As an aside, I'd strongly recommend that you follow .NET naming conventions for both the enum name and its values.)

Comment: Naming: I'm treating the enum as static, hence the capitals. Possibly not the correct way to do a static list -type-thing in C#? The contents are lower case only because they're used that way in the code I had prior to this (which this has to fit into), I'll be capitalising or not once I figure out *how* I'm going to do it. Regarding functionality, I just don't know as the entire system is a bit more evolution than design. Up to this point, knowing the parent and child is plenty. The idea behind sticking to this strategy is that if anyone should want to add a rank, the code will compensate

Comment: You are trying to call methods on enum? Why don't you use classes instead if you are going to use inheritance properties anyways?

Comment: i'd suggest maintain a [Double Linked List](https://gist.github.com/yetanotherchris/4960171)

Comment: "Naming: I'm treating the enum as static, hence the capitals" - no, that's not the normal .NET naming convention...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no such thing as an extension property. But you could create your own class:

```
public sealed class Rank
{
    private static readonly List<Rank> ranks = new List<Rank>();

    // Important: these must be initialized in order.
    // (That can be avoided, but only at the cost of more code.)        
    public static Rank Kingdom { get; } = new Rank(0);
    public static Rank Phylum { get; } = new Rank(1);
    public static Rank Order { get; } = new Rank(2);
    public static Rank Family { get; } = new Rank(3);
    public static Rank Genus { get; } = new Rank(4);
    public static Rank Species { get; } = new Rank(5);

    private readonly int value;

    // TODO: Change to throw InvalidOperationException (or return null)
    // for boundaries
    public Rank Child => ranks[value + 1];
    public Rank Parent => ranks[value - 1];

    private Rank(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        ranks.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Then you use:

```
Rank kingdom = Rank.Kingdom;
Rank phylum = kingdom.Child;
// etc
```

The downside is that you don't get *other* enum behavior such as switching.

Comment: That's perfect! Took me a while to understand exactly how it works, but it's neat! One addendum which this might enable: If I need to parse a string (e.g. "rank=Genus") is there a neat way to cast that to Rank class? I'm pretty sure it must be, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: @user2949952: Either use reflection, or give each value a name as well. Build a name-to-enum dictionary.

Comment: @JonSkeet Could they not use pattern matching - see edit if they are using c#7

Comment: @Scrobi: Yes, but it wouldn't be as simple as with an enum

Comment: This is getting rather circular isn't it? Make a public enum to support a class designed to replace having a public enum. I think I need to go back and re-think the whole design pattern, it seems like I'm doing something silly!

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap your needs into a class.

```
public enum Rank
{
    Kingdom,
    Phylum,
    Order,
}

public class Family
{
    public Rank Rank { get; set; }
    public Rank Child => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Rank), Rank + 1) ? Rank +  1 : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("No child rank");
    public Rank Parent => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Rank),Rank - 1) ? Rank -  1 : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("No parent rank");

}
```

Usage -

```
Family family = new Family();
rank.Rank = Rank.Order;
Rank child = family.Child;
Rank parent = family.Parent; //this will throw an exception
```